# Multiple images sizes AND formats from a single database path?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

The part about sizes is well discussed and could easily be resolved with a suffix or prefix. For example:

with a single path column in database: 'images/example'

I could get different image sizes with a simple string manipulation:

- 'images/example-sm'
- 'images/example-md'
- 'images/example-lg'

Now, how to deal with the image format? It could be webp (default) or png/jpg (the fallback). Is there anyway to implement it other than saving a column called 'fallback_format' in the database?

Answer (score 0):

you can check before take image, if isset format with webp, you take that, if not, you take original, and create on event webp.

Answer (score 0):

You could list files and take the first, starting by the name at the path with the things you've already in your DB, for that you could use Symfony's Finder which is used for Laravel as well